Is there a term for filling in additional entries of a binary matrix dependent on what is currently there?
I am doing a research project, and I found a way to store some data I have about my object into a binary matrix. It turns out that the possible matrices I am looking for can just be found by taking the permutation matrices, and then "filling in" the matrix by replacing a 0 for a 1 if there are 1's to the left of it and below it. Some examples: the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \text{becomes} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ after it is filled in, the identity matrix becomes the upper triangular matrix, and the off-diagonal matrix stays the same.
Is there any sort of term for performing this sort of algorithm on a matrix? I am tempted to call it something like the left-below closure or the right-above closure. Any direction toward papers that have investigated algorithms like this would also be greatly appreciated.
Edit: I have talked this over with my research advisor, and he is not familiar with a name for this. My needs changed, so the rules on the matrix changed. Now, I replace a 0 for a 1 if there are 1's to the right of it and above it, and we decided to call this the left-below closure, since this operation will tend in the left and down direction.
